# ' Square of ' or ' Squares of ', which should I use to frame the question?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

A list of numbers is given. The question is to find the square of each number. Which of the following is correct?

1. Find the **square of** the following numbers?
2. Find the **squares of** the following numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the singular is very rare.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Exploring_Arithmetic/Nd2qOwSShQIC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22find+the+square%22&dq=%22find+the+square%22&printsec=frontcover)) After the class had read this material , the teacher asked them to find the square and the square root of the following numbers : 11 , 40 , and 126.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Teachers_Monographs/V1RLAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22find+the+square%22&dq=%22find+the+square%22&printsec=frontcover)). Find the square root of : 1 , .01 , 9/16 , 256 , 100 , 4/9 .

The plural  should be used, as shows this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22find%20the%20squares%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_enhttps://www.google.com/search?q=%22find%20the%20squares%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) of results.

Comment: @ LPH,   Shouldn't the heading of the following content be 'Laplace Transforms of Functions' 
           https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceXform/FwdLaplace/LaplaceFuncs.html

Comment: @LelouchYagami Were you given a plain list the plural would make sense; however, what is being shown  is the calculation for each one of  the functions;  so you can think  of it  as the _process_ (the transformation of functions  through transform theory (that due to Laplace)). When you study the process, you study the Laplace Transform.